# How can I create a vector based on a variable type

Tags: c++

I'm using a template function, which the goal is reciever a vector and a function, and return the function type.

> ```
> template <typename T, typename Function>
> auto apply(const std::vector<T>& V, const Function &F){
>     vector<Function> x; # ERROR HERE
>     return x;
> }
> ```

But the IDE give me error (http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/ee6ce2127e013a18):

```
/usr/local/include/c++/10.2.0/ext/new_allocator.h: In instantiation of 'class __gnu_cxx::new_allocator<double(double)>':
/usr/local/include/c++/10.2.0/bits/allocator.h:116:11:   required from 'class std::allocator<double(double)>'
/usr/local/include/c++/10.2.0/bits/stl_vector.h:87:21:   required from 'struct std::_Vector_base<double(double), std::allocator<double(double)> >'
/usr/local/include/c++/10.2.0/bits/stl_vector.h:389:11:   required from 'class std::vector<double(double), std::allocator<double(double)> >'
main.cpp:10:22:   required from 'auto apply(const std::vector<T>&, const Function&) [with T = int; Function = double(double)]'
main.cpp:19:39:   required from here
/usr/local/include/c++/10.2.0/ext/new_allocator.h:96:7: error: 'const _Tp* __gnu_cxx::new_allocator<_Tp>::address(__gnu_cxx::new_allocator<_Tp>::const_reference) const [with _Tp = double(double); __gnu_cxx::new_allocator<_Tp>::const_pointer = double (*)(double); __gnu_cxx::new_allocator<_Tp>::const_reference = double (&)(double)]' cannot be overloaded with '_Tp* __gnu_cxx::new_allocator<_Tp>::address(__gnu_cxx::new_allocator<_Tp>::reference) const [with _Tp = double(double); __gnu_cxx::new_allocator<_Tp>::pointer = double (*)(double); __gnu_cxx::new_allocator<_Tp>::reference = double (&)(double)]'
   96 |       address(const_reference __x) const _GLIBCXX_NOEXCEPT
      |       ^~~~~~~
/usr/local/include/c++/10.2.0/ext/new_allocator.h:92:7: note: previous declaration '_Tp* __gnu_cxx::new_allocator<_Tp>::address(__gnu_cxx::new_allocator<_Tp>::reference) const [with _Tp = double(double); __gnu_cxx::new_allocator<_Tp>::pointer = double (*)(double); __gnu_cxx::new_allocator<_Tp>::reference = double (&)(double)]'
   92 |       address(reference __x) const _GLIBCXX_NOEXCEPT
      |       ^~~~~~~
main.cpp: In function 'int main(int, char**)':
main.cpp:19:31: error: conversion from 'vector<double(double),allocator<double(double)>>' to non-scalar type 'vector<double,allocator<double>>' requested
   19 |     vector<double> r = ::apply(v, seno);
      |                        ~~~~~~~^~~~~~~~~
```

This is call of the main function.

> ```
> double seno( double n ) { return sin(n); }
>
> int main( int argc, char* argv[]) {
>
>     vector<int> v{ 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 };
>     vector<double> r = ::apply(v, seno);
>     cout << r;
>
>     return 0;
> }
> ```

I don't know what I'm doing wrong, so How can I improve this method and pass trough this error?

EDIT: The purpse to generalize the in method insted of using double in the vector is because I want o re-use in another way. So I've generalize the most that I can.

Comment: Can you put together a [mcve] to give more context?

Comment: I've editted the post.

Comment: Hint: `vector<Function>` vs. `vector<double>`

Comment: I know that i can use double. But, I want to take Function because type that I will recive could change. So I wonder that I could create in that way.

Comment: What would you have written if you wanted to hardcode a single type instead of using templates?

Comment: Why do you want a function named `apply` that creates a vector of functions? Wouldn't you want to to apply the function to the values in the vector and produce a vector of doubles?

Comment: Oh, this does reproduce. http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/ee6ce2127e013a18, except that the error isn't at the line you said, or is it _quite_ the message you said.

Comment: Do you want `::apply` to return a `vector<double>` or `vector<Function>`? because right now you're trying to do both at the same time, and that's what the error says.

Comment: What do you want to return from `apply`? vector of functions or vector of (function) results?

Comment: Sorry, my itent was return a vector of (function) results.

Comment: The main to is to reutilize the apply to always return a vector<Function>, the problem is that, when I try to do that. I got the error: In template: multiple overloads of 'address' instantiate to the same signature 'int (*(int (&)(int)) __attribute__((thiscall)) const noexcept)(int)'

Comment: The problem with your question is that you don't explain your problem clearly and information is misleading. You tell that the vector contains doubles but in fact, it contain function object. You need to put a lot more effort in your question as otherwise, people won't put effort in answering you.

Comment: @xxxprincemaker Your last comment says that what I wrote as an answer isn't what you are actually trying to do.  So I am going to guess again: if you want to return a vector of functions that, when run, return the result of F on each of the ints passed in, then consider a vector of std::function, each of which is created with std::bind so the function knows what it's parameter will be.  Or, if it is something else you are after, then please explain further.

Answer (score 1):

`vector<Function> x; // ERROR HERE` defines a vector of function pointers.  But that's not what you want - you want a vector of the return type of the function.  And that's what `decltype()` is for.

In your apply function, `F` is the function to be called and `T` is the type of the values in the vector being passed in.   That means `T()` is the default value of the items in the vector (in this case the default value of int is 0).  Then, `F(T())` would actually call the function with 0 and return something so `decltype(F(T()))` tells you the type of the thing returned.

That means you need to write `vector<decltype(F(T()))> x;` instead.

`T()` works because the type is `int` and it is default constructible. As @alterigel said in the comments `std::declval<T>()` is better when the type is not default constructible.

So `vector<decltype(F(std::declval<T>()))> x;` might be needed in some situations.

The whole program would look like:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <cmath>
using namespace std;

template <typename T, typename Function>
auto apply(const std::vector<T>& V, const Function &F) {
    vector<decltype(F(T()))> x;
    for(auto a : V)
        x.push_back(F(a));
    return x;
}

double seno( double n ) { return sin(n); }

int main( int argc, char* argv[]) {
    vector<int> v{ 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 };
    vector<double> r = ::apply(v, seno);
    for (auto a : r)
        cout << a << " ";
    return 0;
}
```

Try it here: https://onlinegdb.com/SknTsVaHO

Comment: `decltype(F(std::declval<T>()))` would be a better choice in case `T` is not default-constructible, or better yet,  `std::invoke_result_t<F, T>` if C++17 is available

Comment: @alterigel thanks for the advice, I'll edit the answer.